# Which version of Oracle supports Streams

Tags: oracle-10g, oracle-streams

I am using Oracle 10g Express Edition. I want to enable the streams feature in my current edition. However, when I searched on the net I couldn't find any information regarding streams setup on Oracle XE

Can anyone tell me which version of Oracle supports streams? Is it only the Enterprise Edition that supports it? If yes how can I add streams support to my express  or standard editions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XE does not support Streams, as officially documented. SE and SE1 support Streams but without redo capture. EE and PE (Personal Edition) fully support Streams, and also support Logical Standby.

Comment: ok thanks..what is the difference between Enterprise edition and personal edition (PE) in Oracle..from where can I download the Personal edition for free?

Comment: also can you provide link to documentation: "XE does not support streams, as officially documented" as u said

Comment: PE is not free so contact your favorite Oracle salesperson :-)